# this.style.background is returning wrong value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create an RGB color guessing game. The premise is that each time someone clicks on a div, the function should retrieve it's color value and match it with the random color value(pre-selected) out of a given number of color values.

Now, the game has two difficulty levels. Easy and hard. The code for the two levels is almost same, the number of color divs in easy are 3, while in the case of hard, the number of color divs is 6.

However, while in easy mode, the function is retrieving a color value which belongs to none of the three divs. In fact, it is returning the background color value.

Here is the code

```js
 var colors = randomColors(6);

 var easyColor = [];

 var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");

function color() {
 var a = Math.floor(Math.random()*250);
 var b = Math.floor(Math.random()*250);
 var c = Math.floor(Math.random()*250);
 return  "rgb("+ [(a),(b),(c)].join(', ') + ")";
}

function randomColors(num) {
  var arr = [];

  for(var i =0; i < num; i++) {
    arr.push(color());
  }

  return arr;
}
// Tried to generate different set of colors for easy mode. Still working on it.

  for(var x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    easyColor[x] = color();
  }

var easyRandomColor = easyColor[Math.floor(Math.random()*easyColor.length)];

// selecting hard difficulty works same as playing again, hence the reload()

document.getElementById("hard").addEventListener("click", function() {
  
  window.location.reload();

});

document.getElementById("reset").addEventListener("click", function() {
  window.location.reload();
});

var squareColor;

// setting up the easy level of the game

document.getElementById("easy").addEventListener("click", function() {

  document.getElementById("header").style.background = "#232323";  

  for(var y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
    squares[y].style.background = easyColor[y];
  }

  for(var z = 3; z < 6; z++) {
    squares[z].style.background = "#232323";
  }
  
  easyRandomColor = easyColor[Math.floor(Math.random()*easyColor.length)];

  document.getElementById("guess").textContent = easyRandomColor;

// setting up the background colors of easy level squares

  for(var j = 0; j < easyColor.length; j++)
  
  squares[j].addEventListener("click", function() {
    
        squareColor = this.style.background;

        console.log(squareColor, easyRandomColor);
    
        if(squareColor === easyRandomColor) {
      
          document.getElementById("header").style.background = name;

          document.getElementById("display").textContent = "Correct!";

          document.getElementById("reset").textContent = "Play again?";

      
          for(var k = 0; k < easyColor.length; k++) {
            squares[k].style.background = name;
          }

    }   else{
          this.style.background = "#232323";
          document.getElementById("display").textContent = "Try again.";
    }
        
    });

  document.getElementById("easy").classList.add("selected");
  document.getElementById("hard").classList.remove("selected");


});


var randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];

//changing the RGB in h1 to rgb of one the squares

document.getElementById("guess").textContent = randomColor; 

//assigning colors to the squares and adding the click event

for(var j = 0; j < squares.length; j++) { 
 
  squares[j].style.background = colors[j];
  
  squares[j].addEventListener("click", function() {
  
  var name = this.style.background;

  // console.log(name, randomColor);
  
  if(name === randomColor) {
   
    document.getElementById("header").style.background = name;

    document.getElementById("display").textContent = "Correct!";

    document.getElementById("reset").textContent = "Play again?";

    
    for(var k = 0; k < squares.length; k++) {
     squares[k].style.background = name;
    }

  } else{
   this.style.background = "#232323";
    document.getElementById("display").textContent = "Try again.";
  }
     
  });
}
```

```css
body {
 background-color: #232323;
 margin: 0;
}

html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.square {
 width: 30%;
 /*background: purple;*/
 padding-bottom: 30%;
 float: left;
 margin: 1.66%;
    transition: 0.2s ease-in;
    border-radius: 6%;
}

#container {
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 600px;
}

h1, h3 {
  color: white;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 0.5%;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#header {
  transition: 0.2s ease-in;
}

#nav {
 margin-top: 0;
 padding-top: 0;
 background: white;
 max-width: 100%;
 clear: left;
}

#nav p {
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
 max-width: 580px;
}

#reset {
 position: relative;
}

#hard {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
}

#easy {
 position: absolute;
 right: 50px;
}

#display {
 position: relative;
 left: 27%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>RGBA Guess</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="colorgame.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
  <h3>
    The Great
  </h3>
  
  <h1>
   <span id="guess">number</span>
  </h1>
  
  <h3>
    Guessing Game
  </h3>
</div>

<div id="nav">
    <p>
      <button id="reset">New Colors</button>
      <span id="display"></span>
      <button id="easy">Easy</button>
      <button id="hard" class="selected">Hard</button> 
    </p>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <div class="square" id="sqaure1"></div>
  <div class="square" id="sqaure2"></div>
  <div class="square" id="sqaure3"></div>
 <div class="square" id="sqaure4"></div>
 <div class="square" id="sqaure5"></div>
 <div class="square" id="sqaure6"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="colorgame.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I know, there is a better way to do this. I can instead call the randomColors(3) in easy mode, but I want to know what is it that I am doing wrong so that I can avoid it in the future.

Than You

Comment: What a fun little game =) nicely done.

Comment: Don't use `element.style.background`, this is a shortcut for a lot of different properties (position repeat etc.), and you can't know what will be the output (e.g FF outputs all the different properties while chrome doesn't). Better to use `element.style.backgroundColor` instead, but even then, you can't know for sure that it won't convert your rgb value to an hexadecimal notation. So, the probably best approach would be to store references of both your colors and your elements in arrays, and just check for their respective index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the function is retrieving the wrong colour in easy mode is because you did not remove your hard mode click event listeners from the elements.

> To explain the weird behaviour you are seeing where the colour
>   being logged is *rgb(35, 35, 35)*. What is happening is the original
>   click event still attached is running first, and going to the
>   statement's else condition and setting it to that colour. Ie. when you make a
>   block disappear. To understand this just run through in your head what
>   would happen if both those click events executed one after another.
>   First hard than easy.

What you instead want to do is attach your click events once, and use a declared function at global scope. Which you can use for both the easy clicks and hard clicks. The reason you want to declare it is so you can remove it from the hidden squares with removeEventListener.

So in the future, just remember to clean up your click events when changing states. That is the lesson to learn here.

JSFiddle fixing your bug:
https://jsfiddle.net/jx6y0gt1/5/

Here is a fixed code snippet:

```js
var colors = randomColors(6);

var easyColor = [];

var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");

function color() {
  var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 250);
  var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 250);
  var c = Math.floor(Math.random() * 250);
  return "rgb(" + [(a), (b), (c)].join(', ') + ")";
}

function randomColors(num) {
    var arr = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      arr.push(color());
    }

    return arr;
  }
  // Tried to generate different set of colors for easy mode. Still working on it.

for (var x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
  easyColor[x] = color();
}

var easyRandomColor = easyColor[Math.floor(Math.random() * easyColor.length)];

// selecting hard difficulty works same as playing again, hence the reload()

document.getElementById("hard").addEventListener("click", function() {

  window.location.reload();

});

document.getElementById("reset").addEventListener("click", function() {
  window.location.reload();
});

var squareColor;

// setting up the easy level of the game

document.getElementById("easy").addEventListener("click", function() {

  document.getElementById("header").style.background = "#232323";

  for (var y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
    squares[y].style.background = easyColor[y];
  }

  for (var z = 3; z < 6; z++) {
    squares[z].style.background = "#232323";
    squares[z].removeEventListener("click", squareClicked);
  }

  randomColor = easyColor[Math.floor(Math.random() * easyColor.length)];

  document.getElementById("guess").textContent = easyRandomColor;
  document.getElementById("easy").classList.add("selected");
  document.getElementById("hard").classList.remove("selected");
});


var randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];

//changing the RGB in h1 to rgb of one the squares

document.getElementById("guess").textContent = randomColor;

//assigning colors to the squares and adding the click event

for (var j = 0; j < squares.length; j++) {

  squares[j].style.background = colors[j];

  squares[j].addEventListener("click", squareClicked);
}

function squareClicked() {
  var name = this.style.background;

  // console.log(name, randomColor);

  if (name === randomColor) {

    document.getElementById("header").style.background = name;

    document.getElementById("display").textContent = "Correct!";

    document.getElementById("reset").textContent = "Play again?";


    for (var k = 0; k < squares.length; k++) {
      squares[k].style.background = name;
    }

  } else {
    this.style.background = "#232323";
    document.getElementById("display").textContent = "Try again.";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #232323;
  margin: 0;
}
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.square {
  width: 30%;
  /*background: purple;*/
  padding-bottom: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin: 1.66%;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in;
  border-radius: 6%;
}
#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 600px;
}
h1,
h3 {
  color: white;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 0.5%;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#header {
  transition: 0.2s ease-in;
}
#nav {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  background: white;
  max-width: 100%;
  clear: left;
}
#nav p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 580px;
}
#reset {
  position: relative;
}
#hard {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
#easy {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
}
#display {
  position: relative;
  left: 27%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <h3>
    The Great
  </h3>

    <h1>
   <span id="guess">number</span>
  </h1>

    <h3>
    Guessing Game
  </h3>
  </div>

  <div id="nav">
    <p>
      <button id="reset">New Colors</button>
      <span id="display"></span>
      <button id="easy">Easy</button>
      <button id="hard" class="selected">Hard</button>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="container">
    <div class="square" id="sqaure1"></div>
    <div class="square" id="sqaure2"></div>
    <div class="square" id="sqaure3"></div>
    <div class="square" id="sqaure4"></div>
    <div class="square" id="sqaure5"></div>
    <div class="square" id="sqaure6"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Changes I have made**

Add this to the bottom of your code:

```
function squareClicked() {
    var name = this.style.background;

  // console.log(name, randomColor);

  if(name === randomColor) {

    document.getElementById("header").style.background = name;

    document.getElementById("display").textContent = "Correct!";

    document.getElementById("reset").textContent = "Play again?";


    for(var k = 0; k < squares.length; k++) {
     squares[k].style.background = name;
    }

  } else{
    this.style.background = "#232323";
    document.getElementById("display").textContent = "Try again.";
  }
}
```

Use it as a listener with your elements like this:

```
for(var j = 0; j < squares.length; j++) { 

  squares[j].style.background = colors[j];

  squares[j].addEventListener("click", squareClicked);
}
```

In your switch to easy mode, set the value of randomColor from your easy colors, and delete your loop to reattach the click events, they are already there.

```
randomColor = easyColor[Math.floor(Math.random()*easyColor.length)];
```

Also a secondary bug when you switch to easy mode you can still click the hidden squares. Deactivate those squares in easy mode so they can not be clicked:

```
for(var j = 3; j < squares.length; j++) {
    squares[j].removeEventListener("click", squareClicked);
}
```

Comment: Hey, this worked. Thank you, the explanation was great too. 

I have to ask something, can I use randomColor for both cases? I have removed easyRandomColor from the code, and it didn't affect the game in anyway.

Comment: Yup it would be safe to remove easyRandomColor since it is not being used. Using randomColor for both cases is just fine, because we update it's value when changing modes. Maybe a better name for that variable is correctGuessRandomColor.